How to search by multiple filters with Firebase in my Flutter app?
I made a search bar for my Flutter App and put a filtering button next to this search bar.
When the user clicks on this filtering button, a 'bottom sheet' will open on the screen and user can select multiple filter (refer image) and apply
I want only the ads that match those filters to be shown on the screen. On the bottom sheet that opens, the user should be able to view the list of ads with the fields in the image (type, age, sex, gender, etc.). It would be easy if I used only type as a range filter option and paging. But there are multiple range filters and I don't know how to do that.
How can I combine these multiple queries? For the user experience, I want the user to quickly find listings that match the criteria they have in mind using multiple filters.

My service class named PetAdoptionService
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:my_pet_app/core/models/animals/pet_adoption_model.dart';
import 'package:my_pet_app/core/services/animals/pet_service.dart';

class PetAdoptionService extends PetService<PetAdoption> {
  final CollectionReference _petsRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('petAdoptions');

  Future<List<PetAdoption>> getPetsByName(String name) async {
    final querySnapshot = await _petsRef.get();
    final pets = <PetAdoption>[];

    for (final doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      final data = doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final petName = data['name'] as String;

      if (petName.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
        pets.add(PetAdoption.fromMap(data));
      }
    }
    return pets;
  }

  // The function that will search with more than one query should be defined here.
}



None of the code you shared shows any calls to Firestore, so it's hard to say where you're goign wrong. If you want to learn how to run a query against Firestore, this'd be the place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

@FrankvanPuffelen I have no code. I didn't understand much from the site. As an example, I wrote my model class called PetAdoption and my function called getPetsByType that allows single query. I provided the correction above, you can check it.

That code looks fine at first glance. What isn't working about it? I also recommend reading How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example at this point, as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

@FrankvanPuffelen The function named getPetsByType in my code can only make one query and it filters by type. I want to write a new function and I want this new function to get more than one query and filter according to more than one query. For example, I want it to get type, breed, gender as parameters from outside, but it is not mandatory to get them all from outside. The user can either search by type only, or search by type and breed, or search by all of them. In other words, how can I write a function that can run more than one query?

We might have some terminology confusion here: from what I understand you actually want one query, but for that query to have multiple conditions. You can find an example of how to do that here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_11

@FrankvanPuffelen Thank you sir, I solved the problem. I gave the correct code above for the benefit of other friends.

Great to hear you got it working  --- For the benefit of the system and future visitors, can you post your solution and its explanation as an Answer below ? That way we can upvote it, the system knows that the problem has been solved, and others are (much) more likely to find it.

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen Of course I will do it right away, thank you again.

I managed to solve my problem. Since I think that other friends will have a similar problem with me in the future, I have given the correct code below for the benefit of these friends. I hope it will be useful to everyone.
class PetAdoptionService extends PetService<PetAdoption> {
  final CollectionReference _petsRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('petAdoptions');

  // Function that allows a single query
  Future<List<PetAdoption>> getPetsByName(String name) async {
    final querySnapshot = await _petsRef.get();
    final pets = <PetAdoption>[];

    for (final doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      final data = doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final petName = data['name'] as String;

      if (petName.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
        pets.add(PetAdoption.fromMap(data));
      }
    }
    return pets;
  }

  // Function that allows multiple queries
  Future<List<PetAdoption>> getFilteredPets({
    String? type,
    List<String>? breeds,
    String? gender,
    bool? isVaccinated,
    bool? isNeutered,
    String? city,
    String? district,
  }) async {
    Query query = _petsRef;

    if (type != null) {
      query = query.where('type', isEqualTo: type);
    }
    if (breeds != null && breeds.isNotEmpty) {
      query = query.where('breed', whereIn: breeds);
    }
    if (gender != null) {
      query = query.where('gender', isEqualTo: gender);
    }
    if (isVaccinated != null) {
      query = query.where('isVaccinated', isEqualTo: isVaccinated);
    }
    if (isNeutered != null) {
      query = query.where('isNeutered', isEqualTo: isNeutered);
    }
    if (city != null) {
      query = query.where('city', isEqualTo: city);
    }
    if (district != null) {
      query = query.where('district', isEqualTo: district);
    }

    final querySnapshot = await query.get();
    return querySnapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => PetAdoption.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
  }
}

